# Isdate Function Treating This 3/25/013 as valid date

Tags: sql-server

hi good morning to everybody

i am halfway converting my dates from an old record which is a varchar variable basically what i am doing is using this `CONVERT(Varchar, date_column, 103)` accompanied by case statement to check whether the date is valid trough `isdate()` now i am a bit surprise why this date 3/25/013 is valid when it passes the `isdate()` function

i am basically a newbie on MSSQL any insight would be helpful

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

`isdate` does accept both `m/d` and `d/m` order (but behaviour depends on `DATEFORMAT` value).

Answer (score 1):

If date_column is varchar, you are converting varchar to varchar and the '103' date format is going to be completely ignored.  You should be doing

```
CONVERT(date, date_column, 103)
```

And zerkms is right, format 103 is dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

Under default setting of Sql Server, `ISDATE()` function will only return true(1) if the passed parameter is a Datetime/Date value or the passed parameter/Expression/String can be converted to Datetime/Date datatype. i.e `mm/dd/yyyy`

Even if you pass a Date string value which is in format of dd/mm/yyyy for example 05/05/1025 and it can be converted to a mm/dd/yyyy ISDATE function will return true as it can be converted to datetime. Even though you are passing it as dd/mm/yyyy but sql server reads it as a valid mm/dd/yyyy value.

But on the other hand if you pass a string which is again in dd/mm/yyyy format but the value is something like 25/05/2014 at this time sql server will return false for this value and return 0.

See below for examples.

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10) = '25/05/2014'
SELECT ISDATE(@date) 
Result: 0

DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10) = '05/05/2014'
SELECT ISDATE(@date) 
Result: 1

DECLARE @date DATETIME = '05/25/2014'
SELECT ISDATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@date,103)) 
Result: 0
```

Your convert to 103 will evaluate to true as long as the value of month is less then 13 otherwise it isdate will return false.